# How to pass my json data to another class

Tags: ios, json, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have two screen. On one I have some json data listed as:

```
A
acompany
B
bcompany
```

When user clicks on A the value A get passed to second class and I use that data to fetch some json data related to it and display on second screen. I want to save that fetched data on second screen to local storage.

I want to save data to this class:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

const StocksContext = React.createContext();

export const StocksProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  return (
    <StocksContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {children}
    </StocksContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useStocksContext = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(StocksContext);

  // can put more code here

  function addToWatchlist(newSymbol) {
    //FixMe: add the new symbol to the watchlist, save it in useStockContext state and persist to AsyncStorage
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // FixMe: Retrieve watchlist from persistent storage
  }, []);

  return { ServerURL: 'http://131.181.190.87:3001', watchList: state,  addToWatchlist };
};
```

This is my second screen class:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import {
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View /* include other react-native components here as needed */,
} from "react-native";
import { useStocksContext } from "../contexts/StocksContext";
import { scaleSize } from "../constants/Layout";

// FixMe: implement other components and functions used in StocksScreen here (don't just put all the JSX in StocksScreen below)

export default function StocksScreen({ route }) {
  const { ServerURL, watchList } = useStocksContext();
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    myListData: [],
    gretting:"",
    /* FixMe: initial state here */
  });

  const { stuff } = route.params;


  renderWithData = () => {
    return fetch(`http://131.181.190.87:3001/history?symbol=${stuff}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          myListData: json,
        });
      // console.log(state.myListData[0]);

      });
  };




  useEffect(() => {
    renderWithData();
    // FixMe: fetch stock data from the server for any new symbols added to the watchlist and save in local StocksScreen state
  }, [watchList]);

  //let item = state.myListData[0];
  let item = state.myListData.length && state.myListData[0];


 //this is displayed on second screen and I want to save this data even when user goes back to first screen and comes back to second screen again
 let movie = ( 
  <View  style={styles.text}>
   <Text style={styles.text} key={item.symbol}>
      {item.high}
    </Text>

    <Text style={styles.text} key={item.symbol}>
      {item.close}
    </Text>
    <Text>{state.gretting}</Text>
    <Text>yooo</Text>

  </View>
)
let printme =( 
  console.log("yes"),

   route("useStocksContext", { stuff: movie })
)

  return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>bb</Text>
      <View>{movie}</View>
        <Text style={styles.text} onPress={printme}>press me</Text> //passing data
      </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

   );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: "black",
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
});
```

I am assuming I need to send the data that I want to save on second screen to my another class (where I will perform all the saving of data). I am trying to pass my `movies` to another class as everything inside it is displayed on second screen and that's what I am trying to save on local storage so the data is still there on second screen even if user goes to first screen and comes back to second screen using navigator at the bottom of the screen.

```
 let printme =( 
      console.log("yes"),

       route("useStocksContext", { stuff: movie })
    )
```

in return method:

```
  <Text style={styles.text} onPress={printme}>press me</Text> //passing data
```

Although I have it inside text field I need to just send the data once the screen refresh or user goes to another scree, but I am not sure how to do that. Also, when I use printMe() to pass the data nothing works. How can I pass my data to another class and save it to local storage?

Comment: `printme` is supposed to be function, but your code block for `printme` doesn't look like a function.

Comment: Ah, yeah could you please help me how to write that? I am good with classes but with functions I am not sure. If you know can you please post as an answer?

Comment: you could do `let printme = () => { console.log("yes"); }` you can write multi-line if you want to. Also, i dont know what you exactly want to do with this. `route("useStocksContext", { stuff: movie })` as route is not a function, and then useStocksContext is a hook not a component.

Comment: Well, I am trying to pass the `movies` data to another class and I wrote just console to check if its working

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example of [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage).
I am not sure what you mean by 'saving in useStockState', but if I understand that all you want to do is save your symbol to a persistant storage, here is how you could do it.

```
  const addToWatchlist = async(newSymbol) => {
    try {
      const existingSymbols = await retrieveWatchList();
      const updatedSymbols = existingSymbols && existingSymbols.length
          ? [...existingSymbols, newSymbol]
          : [newSymbol];
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(
        "@MyApp:symbols",
        JSON.stringify(updatedSymbols) // convert to string before storing
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  const retrieveWatchList = async () => {
    try {
      const currentSymbolsStr = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@MyApp:symbols"); // get what's already in storage
      return JSON.parse(currentSymbolsStr) || []; // convert to list
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

You can call `retrieveWatchList` inside `useEffect` to load your movies into the state or context.

Comment: I meant to save all the details of a particular symbol, Each symbol has close, high, low etc values. In my code, I want to save the `movies` data. Does that make sense?